# Encrypting and Decrypting Password

Tags: java, password-encryption

I am using this code to encrypt and decrypt password

```
public class SecureDigester
{
    private static final char digits[] =
           { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
                 'F' };

           private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b)
           {
              StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer(b.length);
              for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
              {
                 hexString.append(digits[(b[i] & 0xF0) >> 4]);
                 hexString.append(digits[b[i] & 0x0F]);
              }
              return hexString.toString();
           }

           public static String digest(String plaintext)
           {
              try
              {
                 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                 md.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                 byte[] mdBytes = md.digest();
                 String hashString = byteArrayToHexString(mdBytes);
                 return hashString;
              } catch (Exception e)
              {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }
           }

}
```

In my login I'm using this code to decrypt password:

```
        String passwordDigest = SecureDigester.digest(password);
        if (!user.getPassword().equals(passwordDigest))
        {
            // authentication failed: bad password
        }
```

Now I have the forgot-password.jsp page that sends the user's username and password to his/her specified email. But when I used the code below I received an encrypted password that was also different from the encrypted password in my database.

```
String Email = req.getParameter("email");
User userItem = new UserDAO().findEmail(Email);
SendMailSSL sendEmail = new SendMailSSL();
String password = userItem.getPassword();
String EPassword = SecureDigester.digest(password);
sendEmail.send(userItem.getUsername(), EPassword, userItem.getEmail());
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Not a good idea to send passwords via email. Email is unencrypted plain-text that sits on someone else's server. Better to send a temporary link to reset the password. Even better to get and store additional security questions that the user provides both the question and answer, such as "Q: Who was your first grade teacher? A: Mrs. Smith"

Comment: @JonathanM Usually after passwords are sent via email for recovery, users are forced to change their password immediately. This eliminates the concern you mention.

Comment: Your passwords are *hashed*, not encrypted. (Encryption implies that the transformation is reversible; hashing implies that it is not.)

Comment: @Hunter, yep, but didn't want to assume that's what he's doing, so I gave him several other options.

Comment: But how can I send the correct password? I only want to provide sending user password.

Comment: @PeterJohn, you don't. Actually you can't. You don't have them. You only have *hashes* of the passwords. See the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Cryptographic hashes like SHA and MD5 are **one-way hashes**. It is not possible to reverse a one-way hash. You can generate a cryptographic hash from any plaintext, but you cannot determine the original plaintext given only a hash value.

Your "decryption" code doesn't actually decrypt the SHA hashes. Rather, it hashes the password the user just typed and compares that hash to the hash it previously stored. If the hashes matches then that means the passwords match.

Hashing passwords like this is a good security scheme, but one consequence of it is that you cannot e-mail users their passwords: you don't have their passwords! You just have irreversible hashes. This is why web sites with good security these days don't e-mail you your original password if you forget it. Instead they provide some way to **reset** your password. If you run across a site which *is* able to e-mail you your password, that's a huge red flag!

Comment: How to implement sending links to reset user's password?

Comment: All hashes are one-way functions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're storing your passwords in the database as SHA1 hashes. This is great and you should be doing this (definitely best practice). The "drawback" to using SHA1 (or any other one-way hash) is that you cannot "decrypt" the hash back to the original plaintext. This means that the following code doesn't work.

```
String Email = req.getParameter("email");
User userItem = new UserDAO().findEmail(Email);
SendMailSSL sendEmail = new SendMailSSL();
String password = userItem.getPassword(); // the userItem returns an SHA1 hash
String EPassword = SecureDigester.digest(password); // this just rehashes the hash
sendEmail.send(userItem.getUsername(), EPassword, userItem.getEmail());
```

The problem isn't so much with this code as with the approach. Since you don't have any way to recover the user's plaintext password from the SHA1 hash (which is a *good* thing), then you need to send the users a link to reset their passwords rather than an email that contains their password. Email is an insecure channel and passwords (other than initial ones which must be changed) should never be sent via email.

There are two approaches to this issue.

- Generate a new password for the user from random gibberish and then SHA1 hash it. Store this value in the database. Send the new random password to the user and force the user to change it on next login.
- Generate a link that the user can use to reset the password. The link needs to be tough to guess and expire after a certain amount of time (i.e. within 5-10 minutes of sending the email to the user). This makes it very difficult for an attacker to exploit the "reset window". The reset link should be random every time and not contain identifying information about the user if possible.

Comment: so There's no way to send the plain text password of the user?

Comment: Not if you're using SHA1. SHA1 is a strictly one-way hash. I would strongly recommend keeping this approach though as sites which send users passwords back to them via email are not secure.

Comment: You can find several articles out there about links that contain identifiable information and potential exploits against them. I just read about one the other day related to the new Mega service [here](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/01/cracking-tool-milks-weakness-to-reveal-some-mega-passwords/). This was for a registration link, but the same thing applies for reset links as well. The more random they are, the harder it would be for someone to forge during the reset window (preferrably 5-10 minutes).

Comment: No, I didn't ask you how password could be cracked. If it is not in the url what other identity information do you mean?

Comment: In my opinion, a good reset link might look like this: http://example.com/password/reset/x323jcdsa9Jvfsa9. The last bit is a randomly generated key that cannot be abused. A bad link might be this: http://example.com/password/reset/?user=stephen_hall&ticks=1993824. Even if I don't know how the "ticks" parameter is calculated, I can probably learn it by requesting a reset link multiple times for my own account. Once I understand how the link is formed, I can request a reset for another user and then forge the link to reset their password. Base64 encoding the link is no good if it's not random.